# Change zurb foundation top bar style on.scroll in wordpress theme using jquery and css

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I am currently developing a wordpress theme using foundation framework on a local host and I would like for the top-bar to change styles on scroll using jquery. I have found that a good solution would be to .addClass or .removeClass based on how far from the top the user scrolls. I have added .active to the .top-bar class in my css. For the jquery code i  have put my code in a no conflict wrapper, because wordpress requires you to do so. I have attached my code below, but it doesn't seem to be working at all.  My jquery does not get any errors when i test it in JSFiddle, but when i test it using my chrome developer tools i get an error in my jquery, please find the error on commented out in the code below:

**My Jquery**

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll", function($) {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {  //Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function  
        $(".top-bar").addClass("active");
    } else {

       $(".top-bar").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

**My CSS**

```
 .top-bar.active{
 background: blue;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fully reference jQuery throughout your code. It should be...

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        jQuery(".top-bar").addClass("active");
    } else {
       jQuery(".top-bar").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

When in no-conflict mode you need to always reference jQuery in full and not use the `$`. No conflict mode exists to prevent conflicts when jQuery is used with other libraries. Some other JS libraries use the $ for a short reference just like jQuery does.

If you want to use the `$` as a reference to jQuery when in no-conflict (as WordPress requires), you could always do something like this instead.....

```
(function($) {
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $(".top-bar").addClass("active");
        } else {
           $(".top-bar").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
})(jQuery); // Fully reference jQuery after this point.
```